# Blade Templating and Footers

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to have a footer that will either display at the end of the page's content or, if there is not an entire's page worth of content, will display at the bottom of the page. In other words I'm trying to make a footer that will be at the bottom of the page unless it is pushed down by content.

As of right now the navigation section uploads correctly and it looks like (from the developer's tools) that the "blade_content" div is taking up 100% like it is supposed to but for some reason the footer is on top of the "blade_content" div instead of under it.

I know there is a million questions about footers, I have read and tried them, but for some reason I cannot get this to work. Any help at all would be most appreciated.

Main blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>             
    </head>

    <body>   
        @include('layout.navigation')
        <div class = "blade_content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>  

        @include('layout.footer')           
    </body>

</html>
```

Pertinent CSS:

```
body{
    height: 100%;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3em;
    position: relative;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
}

.blade_content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Home Blade:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

 Test.


@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your blade must change to:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

 Test.

@stop
```

That lost `@endif` may cause some trouble.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I have a an if statement on the home page but didn't include it because I was trying to make the question as easy to read as possible.